# Docker .env variables to script

Tags: shell, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

I've made an `.env` file which holds some variables:

```
WS_PORT=12345
```

Now the way `docker-compose.yml` is configured is:

```
  gateway:
    build:
      context: ./src/WebSocket
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image:sn-gateway
    container_name: sn-gateway
    ports:
      - "12345:12345"
    volumes:
      - vendor:/root/vendor
      - ./src/WebSocket:/root
    env_file:
      - ./src/WebSocket/config/.env
```

The problem I'm having is that the `Dockerfile` runs a script which is supposed to use the environment variable (running `docker-compose config` does list it out right), but the variable within script is empty.

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo ------
echo $WS_PORT
echo ------
```

Echoes nothing. What am I doing wrong, can this be done? I've seen a lot of examples forwarding `ENV` through shell commands and similar, but I don't want that. I want everything to work when running `docker-compose up -d` without the need to specify anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can source your env file in the script

```
#!/bin/sh    
source ./src/WebSocket/config/.env


echo ------
echo $WS_PORT
echo ------
```

Comment: This does work, however I feel as if this is sort of a hack. I have multiple `.env` files which I wanted to forward to a container...with this approach I have to forward them twice. Changing something in the future would again require changing it in multiple places which I don't feel is exactly what I want

Comment: from docker doc: [Docker Doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file)
`Note: If your service specifies a build option, variables defined in environment files are not automatically visible during the build. Use the args sub-option of build to define build-time environment variables.`


docker-compose build does not support env_file right now, u need specify ARG or u need a hack to it